# if ps aux | grep "nameOfService" | grep -v grep >/dev/null

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am beginner in shell scripting and i am confused about the thing that after writing > /dev/null what will be the value of  if

```
ps aux | grep "nameOfService" | grep -v grep >/dev/null ?
```

Comment: Do you mean the single question mark at the end of the command?

Comment: What do you mean by _value of if_?

Comment: Tangentially, `pgrep` can be used instead of that pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the return value of a pipeline is the return value of the last command (in this case, the second `grep` command). Note that the `pipefail` shell option changes this behaviour.

Redirecting the output of `grep` doesn't change the return value.

You are probably looking for something like:

```
if ps aux | grep -qw 'nameOfServic[e]'; then
    echo service appears to be running
else
    echo does not appear to be running
fi
```

You should use `-w` to match the whole word. I would use `awk -v 'n=nameOfService' '$4==n'` instead of `grep`, however parsing `ps` output like this not reliable anyway. For example, `ps` usually truncates process names to 16 characters.

Comment: "grep -qw" what does this statement mean? I am not able finding anything related to this

Comment: Type `man grep` or `grep --help` at your terminal to see what the options mean. `-q` means "quiet" - don't print anything (we only need to know if the pattern matches or not). `-w` means match a whole word, to avoid matching something like `NotnameOfService`.